# Different label formatter in AChartEngine chart's different y-axises

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to use different number formatters on the y-axises when you have two y-axises in an AChartEngine chart? If so, how do I do that? I currently use the method  `renderer.setLabelFormat(formatter);`, but that sets the formatter on both axises.

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the label formatter per scale, but you can add custom Y axis labels per each scale separately:

```
renderer.addYTextLabel(y, text, scale);
```